# how best to use two databases in cakephp 2.3?

Tags: mongodb, cakephp-2.3

I am using two databases in an application that I am creating in cakephp 2.3. A mysql database, which typically configured, and another database nosql (MongoDB), I use this way for example:

```
$connection = new Mongo('localhost');
$db = $connection->compras;
return $db->anuncios->insert($dados);
```

can I use this way?
  about security ..., what possible problems that you guys realize to use mongo database that way?

Answer (score 2):

You've to setup environment in the app/Config/Core.php file which mean which database you want to use in which mode i.e. Production, Development, staging etc with below

```
    if(env('HTTP_HOST')):
      switch (env('HTTP_HOST')) {
   case "example.com":
   case "www.example.com":  
    define('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', false); // Suppose you're using production for Mysql databse 
   break;

   case "development.example.com":
    define('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', true); // Suppose you're using development for MongoDB
   break;

  default:
    define('DEVELOPMENT_MODE', true);
  break;
    }
```

After that you've to use DEVELOPMENT_MODE variable in the app/Config/database.php file as below i.e.

```
    class DATABASE_CONFIG {
  public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'db_username',
    'password' => 'db_password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    //'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
  );
  var $mongo = array(
    'datasource' => 'mongodb.mongodbSource',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'db_username',
    'password' => 'db_password',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    //'prefix' => '',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
  );

  public function __construct() {
    if (DEVELOPMENT_MODE) {
        $this->default = $this->mongo;
    } else {
        $this->default = $this->default;
    }
  }
    }
```

All the above logic are use for Config settings to use through out application.

Now below code is connect Model to mongoDB.

```
    class Test extends AppModel {
      var $name = 'test';
      var $primaryKey = 'id';
      var $useDbConfig = 'mongo'; // setup the mongodb datasource

      // Now is model is connected with mongoDB only....
    }
```

Comment: thank you! I'll change the application so that it works that way.